# Как сделать белый плюс на floating action button?

Tags: android, button, action

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать значок плюса белым цветом на floating action button?
Исходные данные:

- Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4
- Kotlin
- minSdk 23
- targetSdk 31

Замена цвета в свойстве "tint" не дает эффекта, значок плюса всегда черный...

Вот код:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="286dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="534dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Можете ли Вы показать код, отображение значка при текущем коде, другую информацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В xml поменяйте:

```
android:tint="#FFFFFF"
```

на

```
app:tint="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А в чем, так сказать "прикол"? Почему приходится поступать именно так?